# How can a conductor plate stay neutral when we force it to be charged?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance

At the beginning of this video "[Capacitors and Capacitance: Capacitor physics and circuit operation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_MZNsEqyQw&index=8&list=PLkyBCj4JhHt9dIWsO7GaTU149BkIFbo5y)"
[image]

Let say, blue particles be negative charges. In the video, it is claimed that If we push electrons to the conductor plate, we cannot make the plate to be charged. ***I do not understand why.***

Comment: I think that the assertion made in the video is incorrect.

Comment: I think so, but how can we force electrons to go to the metal plate? For example, applying a electric field, but once we apply electric field dont we effect the metal plate too. How can we prove that the assertion is not true.

Comment: Place a negatively charged rod in the vicinity of the left hand side of the arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

The statement in the video is wrong.

Lets assume we can apply a force to the electrons in the wire, in direction to the place.
As particles, they will be accelerated and Start moving to the plate. This leads to a growing overall negative charge of the plate. This charge will build up a force on the electrons in the opposite direction. Only if this force equals the "inwards pushing" force, then no more new electrons will enter the plate.

Depending on the external force and the capacitor geometry, the amount of pushable charge will vary but always be greater than zero, regardless of the sourroundings. There are for example formulas to calculate the capacity of a single sphere in empty space.

To actually apply the force, one can use external electric fields from an electric source or a statically charged object.

The attracting force of the positive charge in the other plate does however illustrate why capacitors with closer plates have higher capacity.